# Yarn won't find node modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, yarnpkg

I haven't worked with yarn / npm in a while and am now just trying to setup a simple express server with yarn and typescript. However, yarn just won't "link" my node_modules.

I think I have some sort of newer version of yarn installed, where the node modules aren't stored per package but cached centrally (if I understand it correctly), but that causes my packages to not be found at all.

I have installed `express` via `yarn add express` and even added `@types/express` but in vscode the import gets underlined in red, saying **`Cannot find module 'express' or its corresponding type declarations.`** and when I compile the code (with tsc) and try to run it with `node dist/index.js` I get this error: **`Error: Cannot find module [path to the index.js file]`** and `code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND`.

How do I setup yarn to use the node_modules?

Comment: Are you importing or requiring the file? nodejs does not support import out of the box. You hae to configure it to import es files or typescript files

Comment: I am importing the file with `import express from 'express'`

Comment: try this. const express = require('express')

Comment: if you build the project with yarn build/yarn dev/yarn star or whatever it might be, does your project builds without errors? specifically express errors?

Comment: just asking this because VS Code sometimes glitches and shows modules as not found, after you install it. The simple solution is to restart VS Code

Comment: no it compiles fine but as soon as i try to run it with `node src/index.js` (the compiled file), it crashes with the error code `MODULE_NOT_FOUND`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of executing the compiled javascript file with `node [...]` you have to run `yarn node [...]`, for vs-code to work with the newer yarn versions, you have to run `yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode` and afterwards select as typescript version in vs-code the workspace version. That fixed it for me.